# Consulta SQL para imprimir en el Front

Tags: java, sql

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Tengo esta tabla, y ahora mismo está ordenada por id_risk.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente el back-end está con JAVA quien controla petición.

La pregunta es, como puedo obtener el último registro de cada id por individual.

Es decir, risk_test_date me da la fecha y id_risk el id del grupo.

El tema es poder consultarlo desde el front y en vez de representar todos los datos de todos los registros, representar sólo el dato mas reciente de cada uno de los registros.

Gracias nuevo

Comment: Prepara una query que ordene por la fecha dde risk_test_date..
Después necesitarás alguien que haga el back-end, es decir, PHP, JAVA, NODE alguien que atienda peticiones para poder ejecutar-la

Comment: El back lo tengo hecho ya(JAVA), puedo consultarlo pero no se me ocurre cómo puedo pillar el último registro de cada id por individual

Comment: Es bastante sencillo, solo un poco laborioso no te agobies, mira...
Lo que yo haría sería crear una Clase que contenga todas las propiedades que tiene la tabla, es decir, las columnas, serían private int id_risk_test etc.. 
Tal manera cúando lanzas la query que se añadan a un ArrayList<Risk> del tipo de objeto, si tienes dudas dime... También te diria que es una subconsulta

Comment: Que has intentado?, Tu pregunta puede terminar cerrada

Comment: Gracias por vuestras respuestas, me ha valido lo que el compañero del comentario de abajo me propuso. De todas maneras agradeceros vuestro tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pruebalo en https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-sql-online/

```
create table risk_test(risk_test_date date, id_risk int);

insert into risk_test values('2020-10-12 20:38:29', 1);
insert into risk_test values('2020-10-12 19:48:29', 1);
insert into risk_test values('2020-10-12 16:18:00', 1);
insert into risk_test values('2020-10-12 19:38:29', 2);
insert into risk_test values('2020-10-11 19:39:29', 2);
insert into risk_test values('2020-10-13 19:31:29', 2);
insert into risk_test values('2020-10-02 19:31:29', 3);
insert into risk_test values('2020-10-01 19:32:29', 3);
insert into risk_test values('2020-10-04 19:39:29', 3);

select max(risk_test_date),id_risk from risk_test group by id_risk;
```

Ya tenemos la query que nos va ha proporcionar los datos deseados, ahora toca obtener-lo con JAVA.

Primero crear una clase Entidad que define al registro en base de datos:

```
Class Risk {
    private int id_risk_test;
    private String risk_impact_result;
    private String risk_impact_evaluation;
    private String risk_prob_result;
    private String risk_prob_evaluation;
    private java.util.Date risk_test_date;
    private int id_risk;

    public String getRisk_impact_result(){
        return risk_impact_result;
    }

    public void setRisk_impact_result(String risk_impact_result){
        this.risk_impact_result=risk_impact_result;
    }

    public String getRisk_impact_evaluation(){
        return risk_impact_evaluation;
    }

    public void setRisk_impact_evaluation(String risk_impact_evaluation){
        this.risk_impact_evaluation=risk_impact_evaluation;
    }

    public String getRisk_prob_result(){
        return risk_prob_result;
    }

    public void setRisk_prob_result(String risk_prob_result){
        this.risk_prob_result=risk_prob_result;
    }

    public String getRisk_prob_evaluation(){
        return risk_prob_evaluation;
    }

    public void setRisk_prob_evaluation(String risk_prob_evaluation){
        this.risk_prob_evaluation=risk_prob_evaluation;
    }

    public java.util.Date getRisk_test_date(){
        return risk_test_date;
    }

    public void setRisk_test_date(java.util.Date risk_test_date){
        this.risk_test_date=risk_test_date;
    }

    public int getId_risk_test(){
        return id_risk_test;
    }

    public void setId_risk_test(int id_risk_test){
        this.id_risk_test=id_risk_test;
    }

    public int getId_risk(){
        return id_risk;
    }

    public void setId_risk(int id_risk){
        this.id_risk=id_risk;
    }
}
```

Ahora ejecutar la query:

```
private static String SQL = "select max(risk_test_date),id_risk from risk_test group by id_risk";

...

private List<Risk> getRisk()
{
    List<Risk> results = new ArrayList<>();

    try
    {
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
        while(rs.next()) {
          Risk aRisk= new Risk();
           aRisk.setIdRiskTest(rs.getInteger("id_risk_test"));
           ...
         results.add(aRisk);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
     // log any exceptions ...
    }
    finally() {
     // always close your JDBC resources - google it
     // example
     try{
        if (statement != null) {
           statement.close();
           statement=null;
        }
      }
      catch(SQLException e) {
        // couldn't close statement
      }
      ...
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!! La query en el Dbeaver me funciona correctamente aun que no puedo ver las otras columnas, quiero decir sólo consigo ver max e "id_risk" si quiero ver las otras columnas? . A la hora de construir el backend por suerte o por desgracia tengo que usar un framework concreto y es diferente a lo que propones. Tengo que guardar la consulta como una tabla específica y después hacer la petición desde el front. Pero guardo la info de cara al futuro poder consultar tu comentario. Seguro que funcionaría a la perfección!! Gracias

Comment: por ejemplo ==>>la columna «risk_test.risk_impact_evaluation» debe aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY o ser usada en una función de agregación

Comment: Sí mira entonces la cosa cambia un poco es decir, agregas todas las columnas en el select con la función de agregación renombrada,

select max(risk_test_date) as risk_test_date, id_risk, risk_impact_result 
from risk_test group by id_risk;

Comment: En la clausura group by solo id_risk, si esto te exije las otras columnas en el group by, en el select puedes hacer un DISTINCT del id_risk, "select DISTINCT id_risk, max(..... "

Comment: estoy haciendo "select distinct id_risk,max(risk_test_date) as risk_test_date, id_risk, risk_impact_result from risk_test group by id_risk;" y mdice lo mismo...que mierda... es que me hacen falta las columnas de risk_impact_result e risk_prob_result si no de la primera forma me valdría joe...que desesperación la vida

Comment: No no, pero si utilizas distinct puedes quitarlo de despues del as... "
select distinct id_risk,max(risk_test_date) as risk_test_date, risk_impact_result,
risk_impact_evaluation, risk_prob_result, risk_prob_evaluation from risk_test group by id_risk; " Así no te va?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106510/discussion-between-roberto-sanchez-figueroa-and-joel-garcia-nuno).

Comment: Hola!! HE seguido la recomendación de stackoverflow(que todavía estoy virgen en el foro) de iniciar el chat
Gracias por tu ayuda antes de nada
Lo último que me has recomendado me sigue dando el mismo error
Estuve buscando formas pero me estoy volviendo loco con la SQL
Por que si pongo el max a cada columna que me gustaría ver, si me deja hacerlo pero claro me da su resultado máximo y no coiciden
select distinct id_risk,max(risk_test_date) as risk_test_date,max(risk_impact_result) as risk_impact_result from risk_test group by id_risk; (como ejemplo)

Comment: En este caso no se puedes hacer max de risk_impact_result dado que es un varchar un texto, aquí tendrías que hacer un count de risk_impact_result pero esto te dejaria incongruencias porque no sabría vincular el max de risk_test_date con risk_impact_result

Comment: Exacto, y la verdad que no se como seguir...Lo único que se me ha ocurrido es añadir una columna de true o false, y cuando mete una nuevo registro, que lo meta con true ( con un post) y que en el mismo método se actualice el ultimo registro (con un put) poniendo el ultimo registro de un id concreto en false. y así despues podría filtrar por true's. Por que por SQL mis conocimientos quedan bastante limitados....( a la vista está)

Comment: Tocaría hacer una subconsulta, es decir, primero te traes el max count tipo de risk_impact_result y despues harías el max de la subconsulta del risk_test_date

Comment: Al final lo que hecho fue crear una columna nueva en el sql de true o false , y después hago una búsqueda simple filtrando por true. Ya me da el último resultado true de cada uno de los primary key. Gracias por tu tiempo!!